# Range query on array of encrypted data using homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Given an array or database entries of encrypted data is it possible given a min/mix value to get a range of encrypted entries? The min and max values would also be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [order-preserving encryption](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-01001-9_13.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm2FF1rSypKX5pFKMQ1LP4FRhibDvA&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) made by Boldyreva. That is given $a$ and $b$ with $a>b$ then $\operatorname{OPE}(a) > \operatorname{OPE}(b)$ where the OPE is the order preserving encryption.

OPE has already many implementations and OPE used by [CryptDB](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/raluca-cryptdb.pdf) to execute the order based queries to test their capabilities and benchmark on [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/) queries.

Note that OPE leaks information about the plaintext. An adversary can guess approximately the position of the plaintext of a ciphertext lives in the plaintext space.

Comment: Very good, thank you! I was thinking this through on a drive and had suspicions that this would leak data.